# creating/editing gitlab repository using gitlab api

Tags: gitlab-api

I would like to write a script that edits a bunch of settings for several gitlab repositories.

for now I have worked out

```
    #!/bin/bash
PER_PAGE=50

function make_request {
    local page="$1"
    local url="${BASE_URL}${ENDPOINT}?private_token=${PRIVATE_TOKEN}&per_page=${PER_PAGE}&page=${page}"
    local response=$(curl -sS "$url")
    echo "$response"
}


export approvals_before_merge="2"
export merge_method="merge"
export squash_option="default_off"
export remove_source_branch_after_merge='true'
export only_allow_merge_if_pipeline_succeeds='true'
export only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved='true'


for ((page = 1; page <= total_pages; page++)); do
      echo page number $page
    response=$(make_request "$page")
    # echo $response
    # response=''
    if [  "$response" = "[]" ]; then
        echo "Variable is empty. Stopping the loop."
        break
    fi
    # Process the data from each page using jq here

    # Process the response to populate the array_of_arrays with the data
        while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do
            array_of_arrays+=("$line")
        done < <(echo "$response" | jq -r '.[] | [(.id, .name)] | @tsv')
        # echo $response | jq -r '.[]| [.name,.id]'
        # Iterate over the array_of_arrays and print the two elements for each row
        for ((i = 0; i < ${#array_of_arrays[@]}; i+=1)); do
            IFS=$'\t' read -r id name <<< "${array_of_arrays[$i]}"
            echo "i: $(((i )+$project_number)), Project ID: $id, Project Name: $name"

        curl  -sS --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:  ${PRIVATE_TOKEN}" \
        --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
        --data '{"approvals_before_merge": "'"$approvals_before_merge"'","merge_method": "'"$merge_method"'","squash_option": "'"$squash_option"'","remove_source_branch_after_merge": "'"$remove_source_branch_after_merge"'","only_allow_merge_if_pipeline_succeeds": "'"$only_allow_merge_if_pipeline_succeeds"'","only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved": "'"$only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved"'"}' \
        "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$id"


        done
    #   project_number=$(((i )+$project_number))
done
```

But what I really want is to set

- MR templates
- new commit regex
- code owners
- branch regex

I know is possible using terraform but I am struggling using the api.
I tried with

```
NEW_MERGE_TEMPLATE="
## Overview
### What is changing: 
<!-- Add a list describing the changes you have made in this MR -->

### What is the result of these changes:
<!-- Add a list describing the intended result of these changes -->

## Related ticket
 
<!-- Replace XXX with the ticket ID, e.g. 123 -->
 
- [XXX](https://jira.extge.co.uk/browse/XXX)
 
## Checklist
 
<!-- Replace [ ] with [x] for the items that apply -->
 
- [ ] The PR only includes changes relating to 1 ticket
- [ ] I have added labels to reflect change type
- [ ] I have added tests to cover my changes
- [ ] I have updated the documentation where required
- [ ] I have informed the team of any impactful changes"

# Define your new branch regex
NEW_BRANCH_REGEX="^(([A-Za-z0-9]+)-\\d+|HOTFIX|hotfix|\\d+)\\-.*"

# Define your new commit regex
NEW_COMMIT_REGEX="^(?P<type>build|chore|ci|docs|feat|fix|perf|refactor|revert|style|test|¯\\\\_(ツ)_/¯)(?P<scope>\\(\\w+\\))?(?P<breaking>!)?(?P<subject>:\\s.*)?|^(?P<merge>Merge \\w+)"

curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $PRIVATE_TOKEN" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"merge_requests_template": "'"$NEW_MERGE_TEMPLATE"'"}' \
     "$BASE_URL/projects/$PROJECT_ID"

# # # Update the branch name regex
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $PRIVATE_TOKEN" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"name_regex": "'"$NEW_BRANCH_REGEX"'"}' \
     "$BASE_URL/projects/$PROJECT_ID"

# # # Update the commit message regex
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $PRIVATE_TOKEN" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"commit_message_regex": "'"$NEW_COMMIT_REGEX"'"}' \
     "$BASE_URL/projects/$PROJECT_ID"

# # # # Enable code owners with the specified user IDs
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $PRIVATE_TOKEN" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"merge_requests_access_level": "enabled", "approvals_before_merge": 2, "code_owner_approval_required": $(echo ${CODE_OWNER_IDS[@]} | jq -R '[split(" ") | .[] | tonumber]')}" \
     "$GITLAB_API/projects/$PROJECT_ID"
```

the fail I suspect is due to the string not been accepted.

what's a working example? for those expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to use the [Gitlab Python library](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

and something like this

```
def update_settings(project_id,gl_client):
    try:
        # Get the project by ID
        project = gl_client.projects.get(project_id)
        
        # settings = project.mergerequests.settings.get()

        # Set approvals_before_merge
        project.approvals_before_merge = 2

        # Set merge_method to "merge"

        project.merge_method = "merge"

        project.default_branch = 'develop'
        # Set squash_option to "default_off"
        project.squash_option = "default_off"

        # Set remove_source_branch_after_merge to True
        project.remove_source_branch_after_merge = True

        project.allow_merge_on_skipped_pipeline = False

        # Set only_allow_merge_if_pipeline_succeeds to True
        project.only_allow_merge_if_pipeline_succeeds = True

        # Set only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved to True
        project.only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved = True

        project.merge_request_template = 'Default.md'

        # Save the updated settings
        project.save()

        p_mras = project.approvals.get()
        p_mras.approvals_before_merge = 2
        p_mras.reset_approvals_on_push = True
        p_mras.disable_overriding_approvers_per_merge_request = True
        p_mras.merge_requests_author_approval = False
        p_mras.merge_requests_disable_committers_approval = True
        p_mras.save()


        print(f"project settings updated successfully for project ID {project_id}")
    except gitlab.exceptions.GitlabGetError as e:
        print(f"Failed to update settings  for project ID {project_id}: {e}")
```

actually updates the settings!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided script, it seems you are on the right track. However, there are a couple of adjustments needed to correctly set the MR templates, new commit regex, code owners, and branch regex using the GitLab API.

> **MR Templates:** You can use the `merge_requests_template` attribute to set the MR templates for a project. Make sure you properly escape the
> double quotes in the JSON payload. Here's an example of how you can do
> it:

```
NEW_MERGE_TEMPLATE="## Overview\n### What is changing:\n<!-- Add a list describing the changes you have made in this MR -->\n### What is the result of these changes:\n<!-- Add a list describing the intended result of these changes -->\n## Related ticket\n<!-- Replace XXX with the ticket ID, e.g. 123 -->\n\n- [XXX](https://jira.extge.co.uk/browse/XXX)\n\n## Checklist\n\n<!-- Replace [ ] with [x] for the items that apply -->\n\n- [ ] The PR only includes changes relating to 1 ticket\n- [ ] I have added labels to reflect change type\n- [ ] I have added tests to cover my changes\n- [ ] I have updated the documentation where required\n- [ ] I have informed the team of any impactful changes"

curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $PRIVATE_TOKEN" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data "{\"merge_requests_template\": \"$NEW_MERGE_TEMPLATE\"}" \
     "$BASE_URL/projects/$PROJECT_ID"
```

> **Branch Regex:** To set the branch name regex, you can use the `name_regex` attribute. It seems like your `NEW_BRANCH_REGEX` is correct,
> but make sure to escape the backslashes properly when using it in the
> JSON payload:

```
NEW_BRANCH_REGEX="^(([A-Za-z0-9]+)-\\d+|HOTFIX|hotfix|\\d+)\\-.*"

curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $PRIVATE_TOKEN" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data "{\"name_regex\": \"$NEW_BRANCH_REGEX\"}" \
     "$BASE_URL/projects/$PROJECT_ID"
```

> **Commit Message Regex:** To set the new commit message regex, you can use the `commit_message_regex` attribute. The `NEW_COMMIT_REGEX` you
> provided seems correct:

```
NEW_COMMIT_REGEX="^(?P<type>build|chore|ci|docs|feat|fix|perf|refactor|revert|style|test|¯\\\\_(ツ)_/¯)(?P<scope>\\(\\w+\\))?(?P<breaking>!)?(?P<subject>:\\s.*)?|^(?P<merge>Merge \\w+)"

curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $PRIVATE_TOKEN" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data "{\"commit_message_regex\": \"$NEW_COMMIT_REGEX\"}" \
     "$BASE_URL/projects/$PROJECT_ID"
```

> **Code Owners:** To enable code owners for merge requests and specify user IDs, you can use the `code_owner_approval_required` attribute.
> Ensure that you have defined the `CODE_OWNER_IDS` array with the
> appropriate user IDs:

```
# Example of defining CODE_OWNER_IDS array with user IDs
CODE_OWNER_IDS=("1" "2" "3") # Add the relevant user IDs here

curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $PRIVATE_TOKEN" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data "{\"merge_requests_access_level\": \"enabled\", \"approvals_before_merge\": 2, \"code_owner_approval_required\": $(echo ${CODE_OWNER_IDS[@]} | jq -R '[split(" ") | .[] | tonumber]')}" \
     "$GITLAB_API/projects/$PROJECT_ID"
```

Make sure to replace `$PROJECT_ID`, `$PRIVATE_TOKEN`, and other variables with their appropriate values in your script.

With these adjustments, your script should correctly set the MR templates, new commit regex, code owners, and branch regex using the GitLab API.

Comment: none of this actually works

Answer (score 0):

tbat is giving the error

requirements_access_level are missing,

i think one is also suppose to specify those

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).